# I need a code block to exit an if statement

Tags: python

here is  an  example code:

`money = 20`

`var1  = 2f`

`if var1 == 2f:`

`if money < 25:`

`print("you dont have enough money")`

After that, i need something to exit  the if statement (and the larger one, too.)

is it possible? is there something like `break` but for if statements?

```py
item1 = "2f"
money = 20
inventory = []
if item1 == "2f":
    if money < 25:
        print("sorry mate, you don't have enough")
        #this is where i got stuck
    print("you bought the large cookie box for 25 dollars. ")
    money -= 25
    print("you now have", money, "dollars")
    inventory.append("LCB")
```

it simply printed that and appended the LCB, made the money -5 and printed the other message.
(this is part of a much larger code, so it's edited a little.)
i can't use the function method because i'll need the list and variables later on. and i can't use loops, either. i'm also a bit of a beginner  i don't want (too) complicated answers.

quick edit:
i actually found out how to solve the code at hand, but i'd still like some answers to help in other projects.

Comment: How about `else`?

Comment: You put the code that you don't want to run when the outer `if` enters in the `else` clause of the inner `if`.
Otherwise, acquire the good practice of splitting your code in small functions, then you can use `return` to break from any code path.

Comment: The answer depends on your code. Do you really have a string of "naked" conditions in your code? It seems like this stuff should be wrapped in a `def` and if so, `return` is likely what you'll want.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you want is an else statement. It does something when the condition isn't met. In this case, when the user doesn't have enough money.
Example:

```py
    if money < 25:
        # do something
    else:
        # do something if the user has more or equal money
```

Answer (score 1):

Just to build upon the other comments and suggestions about adding an "else" clause, following is a snippet of code to allow for some continual testing with various amounts of money.

```
inventory = []

while True:

    item1 = input("Please enter the item you wish to purchase: ")

    if item1 == "Quit":
        break
    money = int(input("How much money do you have to spend: "))
    
    if item1 == "2f":
        if money < 25:
            print("Sorry mate, you don't have enough")
        else:
            print("you bought the large cookie box for 25 dollars. ")
            money -= 25
            print("you now have", money, "dollars")
            inventory.append("LCB")

    else:
        print("Sorry - that item is not in stock")
```

Following is some sample output at the terminal.

```
@Dev:~/Python_Programs/Cookies$ python3 Cookies.py 
Please enter the item you wish to purchase: 2f
How much money do you have to spend: 20
Sorry mate, you don't have enough
Please enter the item you wish to purchase: 2f
How much money do you have to spend: 45
you bought the large cookie box for 25 dollars. 
you now have 20 dollars
Please enter the item you wish to purchase: Quit
```

Along with the other suggestions, you might give this a try.

Answer (score 0):

Change your code to this:

```
item1 = "2f"
money = 20
inventory = []
if item1 == "2f":
    if money < 25:
        print("sorry mate, you don't have enough")
        #this is where i got stuck
    else: 
        # this only runs if condition in the if statement above failed
        print("you bought the large cookie box for 25 dollars. ")
        money -= 25
        print("you now have", money, "dollars")
        inventory.append("LCB")
```

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the wider code I am not sure exactly what you mean by exiting it. You can group the above into and `if/else` statement though:

```
item1 = "2f"
money = 20
inventory = []
if item1 == "2f" and money < 25:
    print("sorry mate, you don't have enough")
else:
    print("you bought the large cookie box for 25 dollars. ")
    money -= 25
    print("you now have", money, "dollars")
    inventory.append("LCB")
```

You could obviously put that whole statement inside a `while` or `for` loop depending on what you need from it

Answer (score 0):

If you really have a bunch of "naked" conditions then the answers you were given are right. If this is just your MRE and you actually have all of this in a `def` then `return` is likely what you'll want. There's no need to create an `else` if you can completely exit before running the purchase code ... which is what `return` will do.

```
item1     = "2f"
inventory = []
money     = 40

def buy(item):
    global money
    
    if item == "2f":
        if money < 25:
            print("sorry mate, you don't have enough")
            return #exits the function entirely
            
        print("you bought the large cookie box for 25 dollars. ")
        money -= 25
        print("you now have", money, "dollars")
        inventory.append("LCB")
        
buy(item1)
```

Extending @NoDakker example, `continue` is what you would actually want. And I would argue that the very first thing to do is see if the item is valid, and then check the money. Your entire store could be built with barely any conditions.

```
inventory = []
items     = ('ball', 'sword', 'potion')
prices    = (10, 20, 30)
money     = 50

choice    = lambda: input('Buy something else? (y or n)') == 'n'

while True:
    print(f'items: {items}')
    item = input("Please enter the item you wish to purchase: ")

    try: price = prices[items.index(item)]
    except: 
        print("Sorry, but that item is not in stock.")
        if choice(): break # ends the loop
        continue           # skips to the next iteration

    if money<price: 
       print("Sorry, mate. You don't have enough money.")
       if choice(): break # ends the loop
       continue           # skips to the next iteration

    #if the loop got this far the item exists and they have the money for it
    money -= price
    inventory.append(item)
    
    print(f"You bought the {item} for {price} dollars. ")
    print(f"You have {money} dollars remaining.")
    
    if choice(): break #ends the loop
```